# Insert value after default value column in prepare-execute

Tags: sql, oracle, perl

I have a table where i am inserting values using `prepare` and `execute` statements.

```
$sql = <<"END_SQL";
BEGIN
INSERT INTO my_table (name, id, date, region) VALUES (?,?,trunc(SYSDATE),?);
EXCEPTION WHEN dup_val_on_index THEN null;
END;
END_SQL

if (!($sth = $dbh->prepare ($sql))) {
  die("Failed to prepare: " . DBI->errstr);
}
```

As seen above, I use the default `trunc(SYSDATE)` for the `date` column. I need to pass the values for other 3 columns though `execute` statement.

I am not sure how to pass the value to `region` after the default `date` column using `execute`.

```
$sth->execute($PNAME,$ID,$REGION);
```

Will above statement work? OR is there any kind of placeholder that i can use in `execute` for `date` (something like below)?

```
$sth->execute($PNAME,$ID,,$REGION);
```

Comment: What happens when you pass it in the execute statement. `$sth->execute($PNAME,$ID,trunc(SYSDATE),$REGION);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bind variables are being bound to the `?` placeholders. It does not matter where they are in the statement or what is between the bind variables within the statements.

- The first variable is bound to the first `?`.
- The second variable is bound to the second `?`.
- The third variable is bound to the third `?`.
- Etc.

The Perl code does not need to know about the `INSERT` statement, it just needs to know how many `?`s (anonymous bind variables) there are in the statement and provide one value for each of them.

```perl
$sth->execute($PNAME,$ID,$REGION);
```